"Mesh is empty!" error when generating collision shape from mesh
I have a very basic mesh imported for this example. I just resized the default blender cube to a more plane-like structure and exported it into glb and then imported it in Godot.
In Godot, I created a Rigidbody3D and then added that mesh as its child.
So far so good, I now want to give that floor a collisionShape. Yes, I could literally add a collision shape and resize it along to the mesh of the floor, but this is just an example substituting for a more complicated mesh.
To do this, all tutorials/documentation say to just select the 'Mesh' button on the top that appears when the mesh is also selected in the editor and press the 'Create Collision Shape' button.

But when I do that, instead of getting that collisionShape, all I get is this error "Mesh is empty!" that no one else seems to have. I'm quite new to Godot but I do have experience with Unity also with collisions and meshes and Blender. Since we are talking about a simple convex collision shape, along the lines of the mesh, why is this being so difficult?

I added a reproducibale minimal example here

If you've flattened this cube to a quad, it would have no volume. Could that be the sense in which this mesh is "empty"? Have you tried doing this with a cube that's not flattened all the way down to a quad?

The cube isn't exactly flat flat. I just rescaled the cube a bit to look like a floor. But yes, I also tried just exporting a default blender cube, imported it with roottype = MeshInstance3D, made it a child of a RigidBody3D and when pressing that button, same result...
